# Why can't I create a segue using the iOS Designer? - Xamarin Studio

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, uistoryboard, uistoryboardsegue, xamarin-studio

I have been using Xamarin inside of Visual Studio for a little while now but I thought I would give Xamarin Studio a go on my Mac.

All is well until I try to create a segue on the storyboard.

I have two view controllers, one being the main one. I add a button then <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + drag from the button to the second view controller. In VS this works great however in Xamarin Studio when I release the button the segue menu pops up and closes instantly not allowing me to select the desired option.

Has anyone come across this before? If so, how did you resolve it?

Comment: It's rather strange! Could you share the logs from Xamarin Studio? 
Xamarin Studio > Help > Open Log Directory

Comment: Hi, log for the designer can be found here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/z5sxjlljrhy6f16/iOSDesigner.2016-09-14__20-02-09.log?dl=0

Answer (score 16, accepted):

With a fair amount of hair pulling and tinkering I worked out what the issue was.

Force Click on the new trackpads! I had to disable it otherwise the SEGUE menu kept disappearing. I assume this was because it thought I was doing something else like right clicking.

To disable it:

CMD+Space, type Trackpad, open Trackpad settings up. Uncheck the last checkbox on the first tab titled "Force Click and Haptic Feedback".

Hey presto, Xamarin Studio works as it should.

Comment: Thanks, 3 days facing the issue ^^

Comment: No problem. I am glad it helped :-)

Comment: @CarlLaw Just wanted to let you and others know that this bug is being tracked [here](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=42906). If anyone experiences any other unexpected behavior, please see [When and how should I file a bug report?](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/troubleshooting/questions/howto-file-bug/). Thanks!

Comment: Awesome Buddy. That was a saver.

Comment: Glad to help!! Hopefully they will sort the bug out soon.