# Xamarin Studio - Ctrl + Drag to assign Root View Controller

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, rootviewcontroller, visual-studio-mac

I am going through the Xamarin Hello.iOS tutorial and there is an issue when trying to complete steps 6 and 7 from the following...

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/getting_started/hello,_iOS_multiscreen/hello,_iOS_multiscreen_quickstart/

The issue is that when I do the Ctrl + Drag from the Navigation Controller to the View Controller. The Pop over they mention doesn't stay open so I can't select Root.

I am on macOS Sierra 10.12.1 and the issue seems to occur on both Xamarin Studio and Visual Studio for Mac.

---

### XS Details

```
=== Xamarin Studio Community ===

Version 6.1.2 (build 44)
Installation UUID: c2228d3d-9182-421f-ac39-c5cbd1dba547
Runtime:
    Mono 4.8.0 (mono-4.8.0-branch/902b4a9) (64-bit)
    GTK+ 2.24.23 (Raleigh theme)

    Package version: 408000371

=== NuGet ===

Version: 3.4.3.0

=== Xamarin.Profiler ===

Not Installed

=== Apple Developer Tools ===

Xcode 8.1 (11544)
Build 8B62

=== Xamarin.Mac ===

Version: 2.10.0.113 (Xamarin Studio Community)

=== Xamarin.Android ===

Version: 7.0.2.37 (Xamarin Studio Community)
Android SDK: /Users/[NAME]/Library/Developer/Xamarin/android-sdk-macosx
    Supported Android versions:
        6.0 (API level 23)

SDK Tools Version: 25.2.3
SDK Platform Tools Version: 25
SDK Build Tools Version: 23.0.2

Java SDK: /usr
java version "1.8.0_77"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_77-b03)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.77-b03, mixed mode)

Android Designer EPL code available here:
https://github.com/xamarin/AndroidDesigner.EPL

=== Xamarin Android Player ===

Version: 0.6.5
Location: /Applications/Xamarin Android Player.app

=== Xamarin.iOS ===

Version: 10.2.1.5 (Xamarin Studio Community)
Hash: 44931ae
Branch: xcode8.1
Build date: 2016-11-01 20:52:28-0400

=== Xamarin Inspector ===

Version: 1.0.0.0
Hash: 1f3067d
Branch: master
Build date: 11/15/2016 4:13:59 PM

=== Build Information ===

Release ID: 601020044
Git revision: 0ccfcd52b95305ebd5b7eca0d88c1017035910ae
Build date: 2016-10-28 15:12:43-04
Xamarin addins: a39a869d8a78d87bdc6775f696c13a4cc9024501
Build lane: monodevelop-lion-cycle8

=== Operating System ===

Mac OS X 10.12.1
Darwin MacBook-Pro-2.local 16.1.0 Darwin Kernel Version 16.1.0
    Thu Oct 13 21:26:57 PDT 2016
    root:xnu-3789.21.3~60/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64

=== Enabled user installed addins ===

Xamarin Inspector 1.0.0.0
```

---

### VS Details

```
=== Visual Studio for Mac Preview ===

Version Preview 1 (7.0 build 347)
Installation UUID: 2e3e4d33-9cc1-4fc5-ab9f-144375f26842
Runtime:
    Mono 4.8.0 (mono-4.8.0-branch/902b4a9) (64-bit)
    GTK+ 2.24.23 (Raleigh theme)

    Package version: 408000371

=== NuGet ===

Version: 3.6.0.0

=== Xamarin.Profiler ===

Not Installed

=== Apple Developer Tools ===

Xcode 8.1 (11544)
Build 8B62

=== Xamarin.Android ===

Version: 7.0.2.37 (Visual Studio Enterprise)
Android SDK: /Users/[NAME]/Library/Developer/Xamarin/android-sdk-macosx
    Supported Android versions:
        6.0 (API level 23)

SDK Tools Version: 25.2.3
SDK Platform Tools Version: 25
SDK Build Tools Version: 23.0.2

Java SDK: /usr
java version "1.8.0_77"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_77-b03)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.77-b03, mixed mode)

Android Designer EPL code available here:
https://github.com/xamarin/AndroidDesigner.EPL

=== Xamarin Android Player ===

Version: 0.6.5
Location: /Applications/Xamarin Android Player.app

=== Xamarin.iOS ===

Version: 10.2.1.5 (Visual Studio Enterprise)
Hash: 44931ae
Branch: xcode8.1
Build date: 2016-11-01 20:52:28-0400

=== Xamarin.Mac ===

Version: 2.10.0.113 (Visual Studio Enterprise)

=== Build Information ===

Release ID: 700000347
Git revision: 8a8ea655a444b373df6b0a7aaca6092e06c2dddc
Build date: 2016-11-16 07:50:02-05
Xamarin addins: 94517e1a183199eb12a020da231abc5007f6cce5
Build lane: monodevelop-vNext-preview

=== Operating System ===

Mac OS X 10.12.1
Darwin MacBook-Pro-2.local 16.1.0 Darwin Kernel Version 16.1.0
    Thu Oct 13 21:26:57 PDT 2016
    root:xnu-3789.21.3~60/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64
```

Comment: That's rather strange! I am not able to reproduce this. Could you share the version information from XS/VS? Mac: Xamarin Studio > About Xamarin Studio > Show Details > Copy Information
Visual Studio > Help > About Visual Studio > Copy Info

Comment: VS is on Version Preview 1 (7.0 build 347)

Comment: And XS is on Version 6.1.2 (build 44)

Comment: So, I'm still having the issue. And it looks like from my research that other people are dealing with the same thing. I did however figure out a workaround, where I right-click the storyboard and go to 'Open with' from there I select the XCode Interface Builder. For now I can at least continue, but I refuse to believe there isn't a fix for this on VS and/or XS. Hopefully someone knows what the issue is and has a fix.

Answer (score 9):

Unfortunately, this seems to be an issue with the *Force Touch* feature on the trackpad. If you disable *Force Click and haptic feedback* it should work as expected. That fixed it for me anyways. I'm surprised that Xamarin/Microsoft hasn't fixed this issue yet.

Go to **System Preferences** > **Trackpad** > **Point & Click** and uncheck **Force Click and haptic feedback**.
[image: Disable Force Click]
This was also asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39507256/why-cant-i-create-a-segue-using-the-ios-designer-xamarin-studio).

Answer (score 1):

I came across the same issue, from MacOS Sierra and VS for Mac. The only trick that worked for me is to use a mouse instead of trackpad...
This way, the context menu stays open and I am able to set the navigation.